# block attackers from attempting to attack a non-existent folder

Tags: .htaccess, security

This is a curious problem. In reviewing the daily access logs for one of my test websites I found that a half dozen or more IP addresses are attempting to access a folder that has not existed for many years. The log entry looks like:

```
"POST /18/index2.php HTTP/1.1" 404 - "http://www.mywebsite.com/18/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=26:ja-showcase-professional-showcase-component&Itemid=57" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
```

I know of perhaps 2 ways to block the posts:

1) Add each Ip to the server firewall

```
vi /etc/firewall/GLOBAL_DROP
service firewall restart
iptables -L -n | grep DROP | sort > latest
```

2) Block access to the folder via .htaccess:

```
mkdir $folder
vi $folder/.htaccess
```

Add something like:

```
AuthUserFile /home/$my_account/htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Go away"
<Files "*">
  Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Both would pobably work but I would like to find something that prevents the attacks that is neither administrative nor requires blocking a fake directory.

In addition to the above I'm also running into problems with wordpress comment spam; I found the following code which I added to the .htaccess:

```
# Stop spam attack logins and comments
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  #RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteLog "/home/$folder/www/domlogs/wplog.txt"
  #RewriteLogLevel 2
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(wp-comments-post|wp-login)\.php*
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*my_domain.biz.* [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
  RewriteRule (.*) http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$1 [R=301,L]
 </ifModule>
```

ReWrite engine is already on, so I commented that out.  I substituted in the correct folders for the variables above. If I comment out the log related lines, it throws a 500 Error across the site.

Expectations - I expected this to eliminate the wp-comment POST entries in the domlogs, but neah.  Anything?

Comment: As long as you can cover for IP spoofing, sounds like you're in the ballpark.

Comment: What is the goal in blocking the requests? Is there any reason to block - all it is doing is generating a 404. Won't you simply be moving an Apache log entry to another log where it has been blocked instead?

Comment: In addition to good/bad bots indexing the site(s) we're getting many, many thousands of these and comment spam post attempts per day, today almost 400,000. The server memory is maxed. I assume that controlling bad bots/attack attempts will help server performance in addition to being a good thing in general to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at some security Apache modules.

One such that I recommend and use is [mod_qos](http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/). It's highly customizable and you can configure it to block concurrent requests from the same IP to specific locations among dozens of other things. This will probably work for you in some capacity as it's good at mitigating these types of attacks including `DDOS` and `slowlori`s type attacks.

```
Sample configuration:
# allows not more than 20 events/penalty points per 10 minutes:
QS_ClientEventBlockCount                          20

# don't allow a client to access /app/start.html more than
# 20 times within 10 minutes:
SetEnvIf     Request_URI /app/start.html          QS_Block=1

# don't allow more than 4 "403" status code responses
# (forbidden) for a client within 10 minutes:
QS_SetEnvIfStatus        403                      QS_Block=5
```